# Javascript swap divs not working in IE 9 or less

Tags: javascript, size, screen, swap

I am trying to swap divs in IE 9 and less. But my javascript is not working. Can anybody help me out?
You can see my script here: http://jsfiddle.net/pny71Lqd/
Not sure why the JS is also not working on jsfiddle. It is working in my browsers (also IE), but when i try IE 9 or smaller it brakes down.

Find the code below:

```
<style>
body{ background:#f6f6f6;}
#container2 {
width: 926px;
}
#leftCol2{  float: left;
    width: 300px;
    background:#FFFFFF;

    }
#rightCol2{float:left;
width:300px;
background: #FF9;

}
</style>
<script type='text/javascript' src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(function(){
$(window).resize(function() { //Fires when window is resized
    var width = (window.innerWidth > 0) ? window.innerWidth : screen.width;
    if(width < 1024) {
        $("#container2").each(function() {
        var detach = $(this).find("#leftCol2").detach();
        $(detach).insertAfter($(this).find("#rightCol2"));
        })
    }
    else {
        $("#container2").each(function() {
        var detach = $(this).find("#rightCol2").detach();
        $(detach).insertAfter($(this).find("#leftCol2"));
        })
    }
});
});//]]>   

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container2">

<div id="leftCol2">
<p>Div 1.</p>
</div>

<div id="rightCol2">
<p>Div 2.</p>
</div>

</div>
```

As you can see I try to swap around leftCol2 with rightCol2 when the screen is resized smaller than 1024. Actually I'd like also the divs to be swapped around when the page is just loaded (and not necessarily resized). Who can help? Thank you very much!

Comment: not answering your question but you didn't add JQ in fiddle like this - http://jsfiddle.net/b13zh0yh/4/

Comment: Well it is just not swapping the divs. It does nothing..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seemed to be a problem with my emulator. Got a different one and it worked for IE9 and less!